# PDF VIewer android

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-viewer

I am using PDFViewer.jar to read a pdf via my app.

The app doesn't succeed to read the pdf and I am getting this exception:

```
12-10 09:47:25.700: W/System.err(15665): java.io.IOException: This may not be a PDF File
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.parseFile(PDFFile.java:1395)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.<init>(PDFFile.java:140)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.<init>(PDFFile.java:116)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at com.proxycensus.mysharesUK.PdfViewerActivity.openFile(PdfViewerActivity.java:851)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at com.proxycensus.mysharesUK.PdfViewerActivity.parsePDF(PdfViewerActivity.java:815)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at com.proxycensus.mysharesUK.PdfViewerActivity.setContent(PdfViewerActivity.java:217)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at com.proxycensus.mysharesUK.PdfViewerActivity.onCreate(PdfViewerActivity.java:208)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at com.proxycensus.mysharesUK.ObjActivity.onCreate(ObjActivity.java:23)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1782)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1834)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1027)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
12-10 09:47:25.710: W/System.err(15665):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code:

```
public void openFile(File file, String password) throws IOException {
        // first open the file for random access
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");

        // extract a file channel
        FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();

        // now memory-map a byte-buffer
        ByteBuffer bb =
                ByteBuffer.NEW(channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size()));
        // create a PDFFile from the data
        if (password == null)
            mPdfFile = new PDFFile(bb);
        else
            mPdfFile = new PDFFile(bb, new PDFPassword(password));

        mGraphView.showText("CLHed:" + mPdfFile.getNumPages());
    }
```

The path i am getting:

```
12-10 10:03:27.550: E/ObjActivity(16090): path =/data/data/com.proxycensus.mysharesUK/files/05bf2f15-5b08-4014-882a-c0157faa79b9-myshares-doc.pdf
```

I can't access the jar so i can check which line is causing the trouble. Can any one help me? Did anyone face the same issue? Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code for reading the pdf,the error is saying that this may not be a pdf file,did you notice that

Comment: i edited my question, can you please check again?

Comment: Are you trying to create a pdf or trying to read it?

Comment: Is the Permission for reading from External card is set in the Manifest

Comment: I am trying to read from the cache 12-10 10:03:27.550: E/ObjActivity(16090): path =/data/data/com.proxycensus.mysharesUK/files/05bf2f15-5b08-4014-882a-c0157faa79b9-myshares-doc.pdf

Comment: @haythemsouissi: Did you fix this issue? I am facing the same issue. Can you help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong path for the pdf file. Just debug

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: path i am getting, 12-10 10:03:27.550: E/ObjActivity(16090): path =/data/data/com.proxycensus.mysharesUK/files/05bf2f15-5b08-4014-882a-c0157faa79b9-myshares-doc.pdf

Comment: do you have access there? if it 's not rooted the device, possible you don't

Comment: no i can't access it via another app. I can access this only via the my app "myShare"

Comment: in the manifest you have asses for EXTERNAL STORAGE ACCESS. right?